# How to access VCAP_SERVICES in pcf from a react app?

Tags: reactjs, pcf

I have a react app hosted on PCF, with a credentials service bound to it.

The recommended way to access the credentials is to use process.env.VCAP_SERVICES.

If I use this inside the app, the value comes back as 'undefined'.

Should I use this in the .env file or the manifest.yml file? If so, how?

Another recommended solution is to use the cfenv package, but I get the following error while using it:

```
index.js:117 Uncaught TypeError: Arguments to path.join must be strings
at index.js:117
at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
at filter (index.js:287)
at Object.push../node_modules/path-browserify/index.js.exports.join (index.js:115)
at getPortsFile (index.js:62)
at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:13)
at Object../node_modules/ports/index.js (index.js:65)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:784)
at fn (bootstrap:150)
at Object.<anonymous> (cfenv.js:13)
at Object../node_modules/cfenv/lib/cfenv.js (cfenv.js:314)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:784)
at fn (bootstrap:150)
```

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing would be using `npm` `vcap_services`

**Install:**

```
npm install vcap_services --save
```

**Usage:**

```
var vcapServices = require('vcap_services');
var credentials = vcapServices.findCredentials({ service: 'personality_insights' });
console.log(credentials);
```

More Details [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vcap_services)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a Reactjs based on CRA, this is undefined because environment variables in React needs to start with `REACT_APP_`. Also, this is not a good approach as those variables would be public for everyone.

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

If you're not using **CRA**, so maybe your app is not reading the `.env` file... To read the environment variables inside this file, add a package like https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv.

> In contrast with CRA, when using **dotenv**, your variables don't need to start with `REACT_APP_`.

But if you want to make your secrets safe... I would recommend using a SSR approach, like using Next.js.